# How to edit an specific word from a I/O File Java

Tags: java, io, try-catch

So I'm trying to modify a line from my textFile but when i put the new values and print the result, it prints in a whole new line at the bottom as if it were the last line instead of replacing the line i want to replace.

```
 try {


                 LineNumberReader readers = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
                 PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
                 boolean finder = false;

                 String oldContent = "";

                 while((target = readers.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                     if(target.contains(CL.getID()))
                     {
                         finder = true;
                         target = readers.readLine() + 1;
                         System.out.println("Escriba el Nuevo presupuesto");
                         CL.setPresupuesto(reader.next());
                         output.write("Presupuesto: " + CL.getID() + "$");

                         System.out.println("Nuevo Presupuesto");



                         output.close();
                         readers.close();
                         break; 
                     }


                 }

                 if(finder == false)
                 {
                     System.out.println("ID no encontrado!!");
                 }


             }catch(IOException ex) {

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any such way to delete a specific line in the original file. What you can try to do is create a new file without that specific line. This would create a new file but  serve the purpose.

Comment: Nah, there is always a way, think NIO. Or reading all data into memory and writing it back again. How do you think text editors work? But I agree, it makes sense to first write to a new file.

Comment: @Maarten "Reading the content and writing it back again". That's basically creating a new file. Isn't it ? Yes you may keep the file name same as the old one but it'll actually be a new file. Thoughts ?

Comment: Well, you can keep the same file handle, so for the OS it would remain the same file. Of course you would only have to remember the last part to write, or first move it up to make space. However, it's the conversion to / from bytes that may be tricky.